# Need guidance in using REGEXP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT ID, web_name from table_name WHERE date='2022-02-02'
AND web_name LIKE '%https:%'

ID         WEB_NAME

1234      OFFERhttps://www.google.com/
3456      THEMEhttps://www.google.com/
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting the above results. I want the results to be displayed as
below:

```
  ID         WEB_NAME
    
    1234      OFFER
    3456      THEME
```

I want https://www.google.com/ to be removed from the results. Any guidance would be of great help..

Comment: is "https://www.google.com/" constant? does it change?

Comment: Google.com is not constant. It will change

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('OFFERhttps://www.google.com/', 'http.*$', '');
```

I get the output as:

```
OFFER
```

Same when I run it for the other row. Docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) to match the "everything before http:", and depending if you want case insensitive matching (`solution_1`) or not (`solution_2`)the `i` clause should be added:

```
SELECT column1 as ID
    ,column2 as web_name 
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(web_name, '^(.*)https\:',1,1,'ie') as solution_1
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(web_name, '^(.*)https\:',1,1,'e') as solution_2
FROM VALUES 
    (1234, 'OFFERhttps://www.google.com/'),
    (3456, 'THEMEhttps://www.google.com/'),
    (1235, 'OFFERhTTps://www.google.com/'),
    (3455, 'THEMEhTTps://www.google.com/')
;
```

gives:

| ID | WEB_NAME | SOLUTION_1 | SOLUTION_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,234 | OFFERhttps://www.google.com/ | OFFER | OFFER |
| 3,456 | THEMEhttps://www.google.com/ | THEME | THEME |
| 1,235 | OFFERhTTps://www.google.com/ | OFFER |  |
| 3,455 | THEMEhTTps://www.google.com/ | THEME |  |

Which shows with any letter in the match not being the correct case, not match is made on the case sensitive match